# How to configure Jenkins (CloudBees CI) project to deploy to a specific Artifactory

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have two Artifactories (dev/prod) and one Jenkins. Creating dev and prod pipeline jobs in Jenkins, but would like to deploy result to different Artifactory. Appreciate for any suggestions. Thank you!
http://dev:8181/artifactory
http://prod:8181/artifactory
http://builder-jenkins:8080

Comment: figure out a solution, passing Artifactory instance Id when calling service. example

Answer (score 0):

figure out a solution, passing Artifactory instance Id when calling service.
Example
instance id 'artifactDev'   : http://dev:8181/artifactory
instance id 'artifactProd'  :  http://prod:8181/artifactory
in Jenkinsfile, deploy to dev artifactory:
server = Artifactory.server('artifactDev')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).